# Where to find stack trace in visual studio 2010 express?

Tags: c#

Where to find or how to open stack trace in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express?

Comment: Set a break point, and wait for it to be hit. Then go Debug->Windows->Stack

Comment: Debug->Windows->Call Stack

Answer (score 1):

I don't have C# Express available to test on my current machine but I would expect that it's the same as VS 2010.  Assuming that that's true, you need to actually be debugging to be able to see it.  While debugging, select Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack from the main menu or else press Ctrl+Alt+C.